# Fail at entering a try in reading a file java

Tags: java

can you help me with that problem:
I am developing an android app and I need a file to be read from within a class. The code for it is as follows:

```
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                String collected = null;

                try {
                        fis = openFileInput(title);
                        Log.d("FilePATH", path + "/" + title);
                        byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
                        while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
                                collected = new String(dataArray);
                        }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                        try {

                                fis.close();
                                textData.setText(collected);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
```

It fails to enter into the try and then throws an Exception at fis.close().
Whan can I do to fix that?

**Stack trace**

```
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.victwo/com.example.victwo.NewNoteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at com.example.victwo.NewNoteActivity.onCreate(NewNoteActivity.java:66)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-17 10:59:12.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15142):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: fis.close() probably fails because fis could not be initialized, thus fis is null. Just check for null before closing.

Comment: @AskThakare how do you know `openFileInput(title);` isn't doing that already?

Comment: We can't see the log and `openFileInput` does what you are suggesting

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

**First Exception (inside try)**

With only the code shown, it wont fail to enter the try, it may throw an exception in the try before anything has happened, i.e.

`fis = openFileInput(title);`

may be throwing the [exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which it then leaps into the `catch` then the `finally`.

**Second Exception (inside finally)**

The exception inside the finally you see is caused by `fis` being `null`, just null check it before trying to do something with it

```
 if (fis != null)
 {
   fis.close();
 }
```

This is because `close()` is a method of the object `fis` but as there was an exception while creating `fis`, it doesn't exist so calling `close()` on something that doesn't exist throws a `NullPointerException`

**Additionally**

If you are using Java 7 I suggest you get rid of your finally and use a try-with-resources so that you don't need to deal with the close and exceptions that it causes.

```
try (FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(title))
{
//your code and catches
}
//no finally block required
```

Then set your text afterwards

```
textData.setText(collected);
```

Comment: I'm on Java 6. What can I do there?

Comment: I've updated my answer, also can you add a stack trace?

Comment: I'm guessing line 66 in `NewNoteActivity` is the `fis = openFileInput`